# How can I properly add and access items to a multidimensional vector using loops?

Tags: c++, combinatorics, multidimensional-array

I have this program that is trying to determine how many unique items are within some intersecting sets.  The amount of input entirely depends on the the first value `n`, and then the amount of sets entered afterward.  For example, if I start with entering `n = 2`, I am expected to enter 2 integers.  The program then determines how many intersections there are between `n` items (this is like choosing 2 items from `n` items).  This goes on as `k` increments.  But that's kind of beyond the point.  Just some background info.

My program adapts correctly and accepts the proper amount of input, but it stops working properly before the first `for` loop that is outside of the `while` loop.  What I have tried to do is make a vector of integer vectors and then add every other row (when index starts at 0 AND index starts at 1).  But I am guessing I have constructed my vectors incorrectly.  Does anybody see an error in my vector logic?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int fact (int m) {
        if (m <= 1)
        return 1;
    return m * fact(m - 1);
}

int comb (int n, int k) {
    return fact(n)/(fact(n-k)*fact(k));
}

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    int k = 2;
    int sum = 0;
    int diff = 0;
    int final = 0;

    vector <vector <int> > arr;
    cin >> n;
    while (n > 0) {
        vector <int> row;
        int u;
        for (int i = 0; i < n ; ++i) {
            cin >> u;
            row.push_back(u);
        }
        arr.push_back(row);
        n = comb(row.size(), k);
        k++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i+2)
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].size(); ++j)
            sum += arr[i][j];

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i+2)
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].size(); ++j)
            diff += arr[i][j];

    final = sum - diff;
    cout << final;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It could be a liiiiiiittle bit faster if you rearrange cicle for `j` like this `for (int j = 0, sz = arr[i].size(); j < sz; ++j)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i+=2)
                                  ^
```

You want to do `i+=2` or `i=i+2`, else the value of `i` is never changed, leading to an infinite loop.

Comment: I'll be honest; I'm pretty embarrassed right now.  But sometimes, it takes another programmer to find a rookie mistake like that.  Thank you for ending a headache with such a quick response.  In 7 minutes, when the timer allows me to, I will make sure to mark yours as the accepted answer.  Thanks again, really!